# TULIP Trilateration in 2-D algorithm in simpler form

Tags: math, geometry, trilateration

I found an algorithm to do trilateration in 2-D [this](https://confluence.slac.stanford.edu/display/IEPM/TULIP+Algorithm+Alternative+Trilateration+Method) link. But the formulas are too complicated. What is happening here? Can you please break it down to terms like *dot product*, *cross product*, *distance* etc?

Comment: There's only two equations there and though a bit long, they're in much simpler form than dot products and cross products.  They use nothing more than simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let **P** be the unknown point. (Bold for 2D vectors.)

Write the implicit equations of circles 1 and 2:

(**P** - **P1**)² = d1²

(**P** - **P2**)² = d2²

Substract memberwise and rearrange:

2.(**P2** - **P1**).**P** = d1² - d2² + **P2**² - **P1**²

Similarly with circles 1 and 3:

2.(**P3** - **P1**).**P** = d1² - d3² + **P3**² - **P1**²

Looking closely, you will notice that this forms a system of two linear equations in two unknowns:

2.(X2 - X1).X + 2.(Y2 - Y1).Y = d1² - d2² + **P2**² - **P1**²

2.(X3 - X1).X + 2.(Y3 - Y1).Y = d1² - d3² + **P3**² - **P1**²

Use **Cramer's rule**, or if you insist on using vector calculus, work it out as follows.

Rewrite the system as:

**A.P** = a

**B.P** = b

Compute vectors perpendicular to **A** and **B** in the xy plane, using cross products **A'** = **A** /\ **1z** and **B'** = **B** /\ **1z**, and express **P** as a linear combination of these:

**P** = u . **A'** + v . **B'**

Performing a dot product with **A** and **B** gives, after simplification:

**A.P** = a = v . **A.B'**

**B.P** = b = u . **B.A'**

Note that **A.B'** = **A.**(**B** /\ **1z**) = **1z.**(**A** /\ **B**) = -**1z.**(**B** /\ **A**) = -**B.**(**A** /\ **1z**) = -**B.A'** (mixed product).

All in all:

**P** = [ (- b.**A** + a.**B**) /\ **1z** ] / [ **1z.**(**A** /\ **B**) ]

(which is a rewrite of Cramer's result.)